# Where did my session indicator go after upgrading to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, panel, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Session Menu” and “Me Menu” are missing after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133478/session-menu-and-me-menu-are-missing-after-upgrade)

After upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10, session indicator in the top-right corner is gone. I can't access user settings or other menus.

[image]

Comment: Check your screen resolution...that icon might be hiding outside the screen...

Comment: do a gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']" since you're also missing the session notifier.

Comment: I can't tell specifically why it happened, but after doing an update of some of the packages via Synaptic, the problem solved! Thanks for the feedback.