# Mail menu is empty after upgrade to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: upgrade, mail, messaging-menu

After upgrading to ubuntu 12.04, session menu and user menu were missing and the mail menu was empty.
I followed the directions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133478/session-menu-and-me-menu-are-missing-after-upgrade) and the session and user menus appeared. But the mail menu is still empty. What can I do to get it working?

I tried these,

```
sudo apt-get purge indicator-messages
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-messages
```

After this the mail menu contents flickered for a second and disappeared again.

NOTE: The mail icon appears in the task bar but it us empty.

Comment: Did you try `unity --reset` ?

Comment: I did. It didn't help

Comment: Does it work from a Live CD?

Comment: With empty do you mean it looks like in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206762/where-is-the-messaging-menu-in-12-10)?