# Where is the messaging menu in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, messaging-menu

All of a sudden, after the volume slider disappeared, now the messaging menu has disappeared too!

after the last update, now the messaging menu does not show anything written!

here is a screenshot-

[image]

its all that can be seen! now how do i get it back?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I am thinking this is a bug with the theme you are using. Use the default theme just to be safe.

Comment: @jokerdino...i already checked it before puting up the question...even in the default theme,the problem persists!