# Can't login to Ubuntu 12.04 since I reinstalled battery related packages

Tags: login, battery

I reinstalled `gnome-power-manager`, `upower` and `indicator-power` in order to fix battery indicator issues. Now when I try to login, the screen turns black and sends me back to the login screen.

Following doesn't work for me:

- Already tried to login with gdm.
- Removing `~/.Xauthority` didn't work either.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit, and don't know what else I can try.

Comment: Can you login on the console? (via ctrl-alt-f1)

Comment: Yes that is working

Comment: I tried `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` and now get _Failed to load session "ubuntu"_ after login. Console is still working.

Comment: I was able to login again after `apt-get install unity-2d` and `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. Then to make unity start again I ran `setsid unity`. But now the system icon on the right top is missing.

Comment: Fixed with [http://askubuntu.com/questions/133478/session-menu-and-me-menu-are-missing-after-upgrade](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133478/session-menu-and-me-menu-are-missing-after-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

1. Press Alt+Ctrl+F1 to go to the command line
2. Perform `apt-get clean` and reboot with `sudo reboot`

Comment: Would you accept you own answer, see https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer